# How to disable guest browsing in chrome on Mac?

Tags: terminal, google-chrome, macos

I am trying to disable guest browsing in Chrome. It's proving to be somewhat difficult. I have tried using terminal which I was able to disable incognito browser but failed trying to disable guest browsing.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

By piecing together information I found on various forums, I was able to come up with this method that worked on my Mac Mini running macOS 10.15 (Catalina):

1. Open the "Terminal" application. Use "Spotlight Search" (magnifying glass icon in upper righthand corner of screen) to search "Terminal" and click on the first result to open the application, or go to Finder --> Go --> Utilities --> Terminal.
2. Copy and paste the command below into the Terminal window and hit "Enter" on the keyboard.

   ```
   defaults write com.google.Chrome BrowserGuestModeEnabled -bool false
   ```
3. Restart your Mac and the option for guest browsing will be gone the next time you open Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The following commands (entered in Terminal) will disable incognito mode and guest browsing in Chrome.

```
defaults write com.google.chrome IncognitoModeAvailability -integer 1
defaults write com.google.chrome BrowserGuestModeEnabled -bool false
```

See https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/ for a list of additonal options.

Comment: The question was about how to disable guest browsing, not sure how the long description of partially effective methods to secure a computer for kids fits in here as an answer.